# Determine the type of the correlation

Tags: statistics

If the equation of the regression line of y on x is 
$$y=3-x$$
Then the correlation between x and y is //
(inverse , perfect inverse )? 
Does the coeffecient of x means the correlation in perfect as it equals -1 ?.

Comment: I'd add probability tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=\frac{cov(X, Y)}{D^2X}(x-\mathbb{E}X)+\mathbb{E}Y $$
Coefficient $-1$ means the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is negative, so that the corelation of $X$ and $Y$ is negative, in other words, we have inverse correlation. It's not necessarily (at least it doesn't look so) perfect inverse correlation.

Comment: Perfect inverse correlation is when the correlation coefficient is -1.  However, as long as the coefficient is negative, we have negative correlation.

Comment: @D.B. Yes, but here the angle coefficient (i hope you know what i mean, i don't know how to say it) of the regression line, is different from the correlation coefficient, so we can't say that it equals $-1$

Comment: Yes.  The correlation coefficient isn't the same as the slope of the regression line.

Answer (score 2):

The correlation would be negative because as $x$ increases, $y$ decreases and vice versa.  A positive correlation would be something like $y = 3+x$.  $x$ and $y$ would be inversely correlated for something like $y = 1/x$.

Comment: Isn't inverse correlation the same as negative correlation? [As the wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_relationship). And $y=1/x$ isn't a line, we are talking about a line of regression here. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Adam, you are quite right.  Inverse or negative correlation just means that as one variable increases, the other decreases.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)

$$
{\rm Cov}[X, Y] = {\rm Cov}[X, 3 - X] = {\rm Cov}[X , -X] = -{\rm Cov}[X,X] = -\sigma_X^2
$$

So that the correlation coefficient is

$$
\rho_{X,Y} = \frac{{\rm Cov}[X, Y]}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} = -\frac{\sigma_X^2}{\sigma_X \sigma_X} = -1
$$

Comment: Yes caverac.  But you are assuming no error in the regression line by saying that $Y = 3-X$.

Comment: Can i say that the correlation is perfect ? @D.B.

Comment: @D.B. Yes, I'm assuming not error, that's what I assumed from $Y = 3 - X$

Comment: @HussienMohamed The correlation ranges in $-1 \leq \rho_{X,Y} \leq + 1$, in this case you obtain $-1$, which means that variables are perfectly (anti)-correlated

Comment: You need to specify in your question what is the error in your regression line.  In reality, the slope of $-1$ in your equation is an estimator of the slope.  If the regression is a perfect fit, then caverac's answer is good.

Comment: I would say that a perfect correlation is idealistic and actually will not occur in a real problem.  Maybe someone with a better statistics background can pitch in here.

Comment: That means we can not say that the correlation is perfect depending just on the slope of regression line?